# sql_mode works in php but not in an external db management tool

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running the following query using PHP and I get the error:

```
1055: Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '_______.a.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

query

```
    $get_artistid = (int)$_POST['artistid'];
    $q = 'SELECT
        w.work_id,
        w.name,
        CONCAT(w.work_id, \'/\', w.seo_url),
        a.name,
        a.photo_basename
    FROM
        work_credit wc
        JOIN recording r ON wc.work_id = r.work_id
        JOIN WORK w ON wc.work_id = w.work_id
        JOIN artist a ON wc.artist_id = a.artist_id
    WHERE
        wc.artist_id = ?
        AND r.is_performer = 1
        AND r.is_video = 0
    GROUP BY
        w.work_id';

    $conn = fn_connect();

    if (!$stmt = $conn->prepare($q)) {
        echo 'Error #' . $conn->errno . ': ' . $conn->error;
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $get_artistid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($workid, $workname, $workhref, $artistname, $artistbasename);
    ...
```

PHP is right, i'm supposed to have the error. The query should end with

```
GROUP BY
        w.work_id, a.name, a.photo_basename
```

But, when i'm running the same query using a database management tool like TablePlus or SQLPro or else, the query executes correctly without the error. The reason why i'm using an external app is to create, edit, update, optimize the query. Having an app that doesn't pick up the error defeats the purpose.

When I run the following on any external db management app

```
SELECT @@sql_mode
```

I get

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` looks like it's enable. Still, it doesn't pick up the error.

Any ideas why all of the external apps (all of them) are doing this? Do I need to configure something.

I have: Apache 4.4.41, PHP 7.3.11, mySQL 5.7.28 using Catalina 10.15.3

Comment: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY must be disabled OR all select columns must be in your group by

Comment: @db1975 that wasn't the question. Marco is questioning why tools like TablePlus & SQLPro **skipped** the `sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and doesn't show similar error he got from PHP.

Comment: you can set in many tools or configs 'strict' => false. Perhaps it setted at the tools to false.

Comment: @tcadidot0 my English is not my first language. Thank u for explaining it in only one line. By the way, sometimes the db management tools does not skipped `sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. But for this specific query, they do... I just need to know why...

Comment: One question @Marco , the query doesn't do any aggregation like `COUNT()` or `SUM()` but you do `GROUP BY`.. If you don't do aggregation I don't think you need a `GROUP BY`

Comment: I'm not sure why the tools doesn't detect this specific query but I assume that maybe since the query doesn't group by any aggregation then maybe those tools doesn't classify it to be an invalid operation? Side note: your English is actually pretty good. It's not my first language either but I can understand perfectly what you mean. :)

Comment: @tcadidot0 that's a good point. I guess that PHP and the db tools, they use different methods of validating a query. PHP looks more strict.

Comment: I was so use to using mySQL 5.4. Suddenly, the 5.7 version has changed a lot... its more like sql I guess, which is good. You're last point made me do some research and I finally realize that using `SELECT DISTINCT` is a better method since group by is not necessary.

Comment: Disable the Sql mode;
mysql> SET sql_mode = '';